# How to get a script to import Google Contacts to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, contacts

I would like to get a script to import all my contacts from Google Contacts to Google Sheets.

I found one online, but it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContacts' of null (line 4, arquivo "Código")"

What can I try next?

````
{ 
  var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('* myContacts'); // Fetches group by groupname 
  var contacts = group.getContacts();                    // Fetches contact list of group 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();        //Get currently Active sheets 
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];                         //Get first from active sheets list 
  sheet.appendRow(['Full Name', 'Email Address']);// Creating Header
  for (var i in contacts) 
      {
         var fullname=contacts[i].getFullName();    // gets full name of contact 
         var emailid=contacts[i].getEmails();                     //get emailid of contact 
         for(i in emailid) 
           { 
      sheet.appendRow([fullname, emailid[i].getAddress()]);// append contact data to active sheet 
           } 
       } 
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

The below code retrieves all the contact groups for the user and then logs the group name of each contact group in the google sheets.

```
function () {

    var groups = ContactsApp.getContactGroups();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get currently Active sheets 
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow(['group name']);
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        sheet.appendRow([groups[i].getName()]); // append contact data to active sheet 
    }
}
```

The below code returns null if no matching contact group is found with name argument passed. -: [documentaton reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactgroupname)

```
 ContactsApp.getContactGroups(name);
```

The above function should help you with contact names.

Comment: What if I would like to add more collums, like phone number, first name, family name, etc? (PS: thank you for the quick and assertive answer!)

Comment: hey you can add columns in excel using this command `sheet.appendRow(['Full Name', 'Email Address']);`

Comment: Also the following code should help you get the contact details  `var group  = ContactsApp.getContactGroup('name'); // Fetches group by groupname 
  var contacts = group.getContacts();                    // Fetches contact list of group         for (var i in contacts) {
 var fullname = contacts[i].getFullName(); // gets full name of contact 
 var emailid = contacts[i].getEmails(); //get emailid of contact } please do check out classes and enums in the following url [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/]